# Resnick Exercise 6.21 - Find expectation and variance of Brownian Motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let B be standard Brownian Motion. Define: 
$$Y_n = \sum_{i=1}^{2n} |B(i/2^n) - B((i-1)/2^n)| $$
How do we show that: 
$$EY_n = 2^{n/2}E(|B(1)|)$$
$$VarY_n = Var(|B(1)|)$$
$$\sum_n P(Y_n < n) < \infty$$
I'm stuck at the moment, I tried to use the stationary increment property to derive expectation and variance but I am getting a different result, so would love any explanations thanks

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what you tried, e.g. for the computation of the expectation? You need to use the linearity of the expectation and then the stationarity of the increments, i.e. your approach sounds fine.

Comment: So I was thinking that $Y_n =_d \sum_{i=1}^{2n} |B(1/2^n)| = 2n|B(1/2^n)|$, which gives $EY_n = 2n E(|B(1/2^n)|)$ but I don't understand where to go from there? Am I forgetting about something?

Comment: You need to use that $B_t$ equals in distribution $\sqrt{t} B_1$ (this follows from the fact that both random variables are Gaussian with mean $0$ and variance $t$). [And I suppose the upper bound for the summation should be $2^n$ rather than $2n$.]

Comment: ah yes of course, thank you. Although now I am getting an extra factor of $n$ in there, because don't you obtain $EY_n = 2n 2^{-n/2} E(|B(1)|) = n 2^{n/2} E(|B(1)|)$? Similarly don't we get $VarY_n = 2n Var(|B(1/2^n)|) = n 2^{n/2} Var(|B(1)|)$?

Comment: As I wrote in my previous comment, the summation should run from $i=1$ to $i=2^n$ rather than from $i=1$ to $i=2n$. Otherwise it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: oh ok, I suspect that must be a typo in my textbook. Thank you very much!